# Is it proper English to use "a" in "you can't reconstruct a history"?

Tags: indefinite-article

Macmillan dictionary tell us that *history* can be either countable or uncountable, so, for example it is correct to say "*a history* of the Romans" or
"the book provides *a comprehensive history* of the Second World War," and, although I'm comfortable with this usage of the indefinite article before this word, I'm troubled  to figure out whether the following snippet, quoting a comment from History.SE, is proper English or not.

> "real reconstruction" is vague: you can't reconstruct *a history*, and if it is a term of art then it is very obscure. ([Link](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/9121/what-were-the-crime-rates-in-the-american-old-west#comment20249_9121))

As far as I understand, the "a history" there is wrong and it would be better to write "history" or "a story", but I don't know why.

Can anybody explain?

Comment: (Off-topic) Your first paragraph is made up of only one sentence. That is sooo Italian! :)

Comment: @Mari-L, yes, when I write in Italian, I like long sentences too much, especially because they make my writings incomprehensible, almost random words; and I am always pleasantly flattered when other people say they recognize any meaning in my written texts, even more in reference to professional reasons :)

Comment: Yet, again. Amazing! Just one sentence. How do you do it?! :)

Comment: @Mari-Lou, behind my phrasing are years of hard work and dedication, of which I can tell you some secrets only *via* e-mail. Please, don't hesitate to ask; I'm waiting!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question should probably be directed to the author, since he's available; but it seems to me that he is responding to your own original language:

> Can anybody explain how much the Hollywood filmography is, if any, a real reconstruction of the American West's history?

Your question is not about history-in-general but about ***a*** history-in-particular, that of the American West, and it seems to me the poster responds in the first instance to that question ("you can't reconstruct a history") before moving on to a more general posture ("Films with fictive intent can't produce history").

But those two comments are too casually composed to give me any confidence in that reading. *A* may be simply a typo.

Comment: I noticed that the writer ended his comment with the somewhat unusual form *every science fiction is a story about today*. Where again you could argue for it being a "not-necessarily-fully-defensible" usage. But having looked at a couple of his actual answers, I'd say this is a guy in full command of his (considerable) language skills. I think Carlo is excessively fixated on the fact that he normally sees "**a** history" in specific contexts (not including, for example, **"He's got a history, that one!"**).